# Can not load data from webservice from the first time

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

After getting facebook access token, i use it for login in my own web server. However in the first time, there is warning in the log file, and i can not load data from my server, but when i open app from second times, it load normally.

Below is warning log:

> W/System.err: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
>   at line 1 column 1 path $ W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:39)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:27)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:122)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:217) W/System.err: 
>   at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:180)  W/System.err:
>   at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.CallExecuteObservable.subscribeActual(CallExecuteObservable.java:42) W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12084) W/System.err:
>   at
>   retrofit2.adapter.rxjava2.BodyObservable.subscribeActual(BodyObservable.java:34)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12084) W/System.err:
>   at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSingleSingle.subscribeActual(ObservableSingleSingle.java:35)
>   W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3433)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleDoOnSuccess.subscribeActual(SingleDoOnSuccess.java:35)
>   W/System.err:     at io.reactivex.Single.subscribe(Single.java:3433)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.single.SingleSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(SingleSubscribeOn.java:89)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:579)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) W/System.err:
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>   W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected
>   BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $ W/System.err:
>   at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)

What could be causing this?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found the problem already. I forgot to add cookies in rest request.

Answer (score 0):

That error tells you that there is an error when GSON tries to parse the JSON returned by the web service you're calling. In particular, GSON is expecting a JSON object, but it receives a string (see the first line of the error message).
If the error happens only the first time you call it and not the second it means that the web service returns 2 different answers, and GSON can correctly parse the second one, but not the first one.

In order to find out what's wrong, you should provide more details, like your data model and the 2 responses returned by the web service.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. Because i forgot to add cookie to request information from webservice

Comment: I do not have enough reputation so far.